# Cuda C++ memory wrapper class

Tags: c++, class, templates, cuda

I have a memory wrapper for CUDA which does simple reference counting (ala shared_ptr). I compile the C++ class with nvcc, see the [gist](https://gist.github.com/xionluhnis/5134430).

Then I'd like to simply use it in my basic c++ main file as such:

```
#include "CudaMemory.h"
typedef CudaDoubleMemory GPUMemory;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    GPUMemory d_mem(3 * 3);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it with nvcc, I get plenty of errors:

```
nvcc --shared --compiler-options -fPIC -shared src/CudaMemory.cu -o libmem.so
src/CudaMemory.cu(29): error: return value type does not match the function type
src/CudaMemory.cu(46): error: argument list for class template "CudaMemory" is missing
src/CudaMemory.cu(46): error: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)
src/CudaMemory.cu(46): error: expected a "{"
src/CudaMemory.cu(47): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "CudaMemory"
src/CudaMemory.cu(49): error: argument list for class template "CudaMemory" is missing
src/CudaMemory.cu(49): error: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)
src/CudaMemory.cu(49): error: expected a "{"
src/CudaMemory.cu(51): error: identifier "d_ptr" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(51): error: identifier "scalar_type" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(53): error: identifier "count" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(54): error: identifier "ref_id" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(56): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "CudaMemory"
src/CudaMemory.cu(58): error: argument list for class template "CudaMemory" is missing
src/CudaMemory.cu(58): error: argument list for class template "CudaMemory" is missing
src/CudaMemory.cu(58): error: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)
src/CudaMemory.cu(58): error: expected a "{"
src/CudaMemory.cu(60): error: identifier "count" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(62): error: identifier "ref_id" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(64): warning: missing return statement at end of non-void function "CudaMemory"
src/CudaMemory.cu(66): error: argument list for class template "CudaMemory" is missing
src/CudaMemory.cu(66): error: argument list for class template "CudaMemory" is missing
src/CudaMemory.cu(66): error: identifier "this_type" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(68): error: identifier "count" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(69): error: identifier "ref_id" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(69): error: identifier "d_ptr" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(74): error: identifier "d_ptr" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(75): error: identifier "ref_id" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(82): error: argument list for class template "CudaMemory" is missing
src/CudaMemory.cu(84): error: identifier "count" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(85): error: identifier "ref_id" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(85): error: identifier "d_ptr" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(89): error: argument list for class template "CudaMemory" is missing
src/CudaMemory.cu(89): error: incomplete type is not allowed
src/CudaMemory.cu(89): error: identifier "scalar_type" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(89): error: identifier "host_ptr" is undefined
src/CudaMemory.cu(89): error: expected a ";"
At end of source: warning: parsing restarts here after previous syntax error
34 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000018e6_00000000-4_CudaMemory.cpp1.ii".
```

What am I doing wrong here? I read there is something to do with **extern "C"**, but it's C++ code, not C code here...

**Edit**: is what I am doing even meaningful? I have the impression that it's not possible to have a template parameter in my case, because cuda won't be able to do its stuff since it doesn't know what type will be used.

How should I then operate to do what is intended? Is the only solution to have the cudaMalloc, cudaFree and cudaMemcpy encapsulated in external functions which I'd implement in the .cu, and all the rest in the .h so that there is no need for templating in the .cu (but then I'd have the class implementation in the .h of course)?

**Solution?**: so I went for the version having everything in the header, and no need for nvcc to be used. It compiles and even runs, but crashes because of a "duplicate" free, though there are no duplicate frees being called (debug output shows only one).
See new [gist](https://gist.github.com/xionluhnis/5134430/3cbccff5401cbb73da4754d722d86b784f07dc80). Quite a lot has changed since it's all in one single header file.

Now when I run the new main:

```
#include "CudaMemory.h"
typedef gpu::CudaDoubleMemory GPUMemory;
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // testing the self adjoint eigenvalue kernel
    // selfAdjointEigensTest();
    GPUMemory d_mem(3 * 3);

    std::cout << "Memory size: " << d_mem.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Memory reference: " << d_mem.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Memory reference count: " << d_mem.ref_count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the results I asked for, but at program exit, it crashes (so there seems to be a memory problem here). At least the main trouble of code separation is resolved. Oh, and I had to add **-lcudart** so that the cuda_runtime.h stuff is available.

```
Memory size: 9
Memory reference: 0x700100000
Memory reference count: 1
Freeing ref#0
*** glibc detected *** /home/alexandre/NetBeansProjects/GPU_TEST/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/gpu_test: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000104b3f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76d76)[0x7f9bbfd99d76]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6c)[0x7f9bbfd9eaac]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.4(+0x23c32)[0x7f9bc086fc32]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.4(+0x2012b)[0x7f9bc086c12b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.4(+0x26d6b)[0x7f9bc0872d6b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.4(+0x26f7b)[0x7f9bc0872f7b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.4(+0x19e0c)[0x7f9bc0865e0c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__cxa_finalize+0xa5)[0x7f9bbfd5a175]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.4(+0x5b66)[0x7f9bc0851b66]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00408000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 24633669                           /home/alexandre/NetBeansProjects/GPU_TEST/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/gpu_test
00607000-00608000 rw-p 00007000 08:07 24633669                           /home/alexandre/NetBeansProjects/GPU_TEST/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/gpu_test
00f60000-0106b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
200000000-900000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bb8000000-7f9bb8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bb8021000-7f9bbc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bbd2f4000-7f9bbd2f5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bbd2f5000-7f9bbd3f5000 rw-s 369cd5000 00:05 5720                      /dev/nvidia0
7f9bbd3f5000-7f9bbd4f5000 rw-s 368e8c000 00:05 5720                      /dev/nvidia0
7f9bbd4f5000-7f9bbd5f5000 rw-s 368ac3000 00:05 5720                      /dev/nvidia0
7f9bbd5f5000-7f9bbd6f5000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 79644                      /dev/zero (deleted)
7f9bbd6f5000-7f9bbd7f5000 rw-s 38238d000 00:05 5720                      /dev/nvidia0
7f9bbd7f5000-7f9bbd8f5000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 79643                      /dev/zero (deleted)
7f9bbd8f5000-7f9bbd8f6000 rw-s efee6000 00:05 5720                       /dev/nvidia0
7f9bbd8f6000-7f9bbd8f7000 rw-s 382385000 00:05 5720                      /dev/nvidia0
7f9bbd8f7000-7f9bbdcf9000 rw-s 3e39b9000 00:05 5720                      /dev/nvidia0
7f9bbdcf9000-7f9bbe0fb000 rw-s 38eade000 00:05 5720                      /dev/nvidia0
7f9bbe0fb000-7f9bbe0fc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bbe0fc000-7f9bbe8fc000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bbe8fc000-7f9bbe912000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 3145792                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
7f9bbe912000-7f9bbeb11000 ---p 00016000 08:07 3145792                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
7f9bbeb11000-7f9bbeb12000 r--p 00015000 08:07 3145792                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
7f9bbeb12000-7f9bbeb13000 rw-p 00016000 08:07 3145792                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
7f9bbeb13000-7f9bbf3c0000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 13985100                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.304.64
7f9bbf3c0000-7f9bbf5c0000 ---p 008ad000 08:07 13985100                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.304.64
7f9bbf5c0000-7f9bbf6d2000 rw-p 008ad000 08:07 13985100                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.304.64
7f9bbf6d2000-7f9bbf6fb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bbf6fb000-7f9bbf702000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 3145947                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
7f9bbf702000-7f9bbf901000 ---p 00007000 08:07 3145947                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
7f9bbf901000-7f9bbf902000 r--p 00006000 08:07 3145947                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
7f9bbf902000-7f9bbf903000 rw-p 00007000 08:07 3145947                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.13.so
7f9bbf903000-7f9bbf91a000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 3145939                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7f9bbf91a000-7f9bbfb19000 ---p 00017000 08:07 3145939                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7f9bbfb19000-7f9bbfb1a000 r--p 00016000 08:07 3145939                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7f9bbfb1a000-7f9bbfb1b000 rw-p 00017000 08:07 3145939                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
7f9bbfb1b000-7f9bbfb1f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bbfb1f000-7f9bbfb21000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 3145944                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f9bbfb21000-7f9bbfd21000 ---p 00002000 08:07 3145944                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f9bbfd21000-7f9bbfd22000 r--p 00002000 08:07 3145944                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f9bbfd22000-7f9bbfd23000 rw-p 00003000 08:07 3145944                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f9bbfd23000-7f9bbfea3000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 3145953                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f9bbfea3000-7f9bc00a3000 ---p 00180000 08:07 3145953                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f9bc00a3000-7f9bc00a7000 r--p 00180000 08:07 3145953                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f9bc00a7000-7f9bc00a8000 rw-p 00184000 08:07 3145953                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f9bc00a8000-7f9bc00ad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bc00ad000-7f9bc00c2000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 3145790                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9bc00c2000-7f9bc02c2000 ---p 00015000 08:07 3145790                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9bc02c2000-7f9bc02c3000 rw-p 00015000 08:07 3145790                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9bc02c3000-7f9bc0344000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 3145949                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7f9bc0344000-7f9bc0543000 ---p 00081000 08:07 3145949                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7f9bc0543000-7f9bc0544000 r--p 00080000 08:07 3145949                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7f9bc0544000-7f9bc0545000 rw-p 00081000 08:07 3145949                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
7f9bc0545000-7f9bc062d000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 13986699                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7f9bc062d000-7f9bc082d000 ---p 000e8000 08:07 13986699                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7f9bc082d000-7f9bc0835000 r--p 000e8000 08:07 13986699                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7f9bc0835000-7f9bc0837000 rw-p 000f0000 08:07 13986699                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7f9bc0837000-7f9bc084c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bc084c000-7f9bc08a7000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 13985818                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.4.2.9
7f9bc08a7000-7f9bc0aa7000 ---p 0005b000 08:07 13985818                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.4.2.9
7f9bc0aa7000-7f9bc0aa8000 r--p 0005b000 08:07 13985818                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.4.2.9
7f9bc0aa8000-7f9bc0aa9000 rw-p 0005c000 08:07 13985818                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.4.2.9
7f9bc0aa9000-7f9bc0aaa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bc0aaa000-7f9bc0ac3000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 24627226                   /home/alexandre/NetBeansProjects/GPU_LIB/libgpu.so
7f9bc0ac3000-7f9bc0cc3000 ---p 00019000 08:07 24627226                   /home/alexandre/NetBeansProjects/GPU_LIB/libgpu.so
7f9bc0cc3000-7f9bc0cc4000 rw-p 00019000 08:07 24627226                   /home/alexandre/NetBeansProjects/GPU_LIB/libgpu.so
7f9bc0cc4000-7f9bc0ce4000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 3145957                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7f9bc0d9c000-7f9bc0dbd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bc0dbd000-7f9bc0ebd000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 79639                      /dev/zero (deleted)
7f9bc0ebd000-7f9bc0ec4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bc0ede000-7f9bc0edf000 rw-s efee5000 00:05 5720                       /dev/nvidia0
7f9bc0edf000-7f9bc0ee0000 rw-s 38eba1000 00:05 5720                      /dev/nvidia0
7f9bc0ee0000-7f9bc0ee1000 r--s f2009000 00:05 5720                       /dev/nvidia0
7f9bc0ee1000-7f9bc0ee3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9bc0ee3000-7f9bc0ee4000 r--p 0001f000 08:07 3145957                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7f9bc0ee4000-7f9bc0ee5000 rw-p 00020000 08:07 3145957                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7f9bc0ee5000-7f9bc0ee6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff2b5ec000-7fff2b60c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff2b60c000-7fff2b60d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff2b78c000-7fff2b78d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

RUN FINISHED; Aborted; real time: 50ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

**Finally a working solution**:
There were two errors in the previous gist. The new [gist](https://gist.github.com/xionluhnis/5134430/d2a86f1d94cab9a70fce8a9bdda9ddff34738aec) fixed them. Mainly:

1. the data in gpu::internal had to be static (one was not, I don't know why, typo I guess...).
2. in newReference, when using an old freed entry, the refcount should be initialized to 1 (to work the same way as when there are no freed entries available)

Thus it's now fully solved. I also added countReferences to check that at the end there are no leakages (and so far, for my tests, there are none).

**Conclusion**: When there is no device code, we can usually compile without nvcc, we just need **cuda_runtime.h** to be included for the calls to cudaXXX functions.
Thanks to @Robert Crovella.

Comment: What is `CudaMemory.h`? I don't see it anywhere, even in your gist link.

Comment: Sorry, actually the gist references `CudaMemory.hpp` but it's `CudaMemory.h` in real life - I wrote .hpp because of the gist parser which looked to use c++ for hpp and c for h alone. I changed it in the gist. Looks like it still uses c++ even with .h

Comment: There's nothing in your `CudaMemory.cu` that actually references device code.  Therefore you should be able to compile, link and build a library using g++.  You will need to explicitly link against cudart and include `cuda_runtime.h`.  Why don't you get that working to fix any code errors you may have and remove your concerns about nvcc from the equation.  Then after you have a working example with g++, if you want to compile with nvcc, we can discuss.  When I do this, with `g++ -c -I... CudaMemory.cpp` (eliminating any linking issues) I get tons of errors with your code from g++

Comment: The g++ compiler is having considerable difficulty with your non-templated constructors (just to pick an example).  Instead of this `CudaMemory::CudaMemory() ...` it seems to be much happier with (for example) `template<> CudaMemory<int>::CudaMemory() ...`   I don't think this is a cuda or nvcc issue at all.

Comment: This really looks like badly broken C++ code - basically nothing to do with nvcc or CUDA at all.

Comment: Mmmh, well, doing that would mean not having templates, but just instanciating a specific template version. Thus templating seems just unusable. Anyway, I think I found a solution by using cuda_runtime.h

Comment: Given that I found the solution, how should I set the question? Is there a way to make it "solved" even though it doesn't come from an answer?

Comment: Post your own answer then wait a day and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

My working solution:

1. Remove all non-nvcc bugs, make sure it works without cuda-specific code
2. Extract all the non-nvcc code into the .h header
3. Remove nvcc-specific code, use **cuda_runtime.h** instead (and link with **-lcudart**)

Templates are usable by nvcc, I am not saying it's not the case, but I don't think it's possible to have a class definition which is a template, and whose implementation would only be done once, because templates are meant to be instantiated, and the compiler creates code for each new instantiation, thus it doesn't make sense to compile with nvcc template-code, and then use instantiate it with g++.

[It works](https://gist.github.com/xionluhnis/5134430/d2a86f1d94cab9a70fce8a9bdda9ddff34738aec).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the 2 first compiling errors:
1. freeIndexes.pop_back() returns void and not int...
2. you should `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I saw these too. I will fix it. But it seems to be a bigger problem related to c++ templating and cuda.

Comment: Also: it should be `template<class S>` and not _typename_. but see edit, it's not the main trouble.